# C++ Operator Overloading Error

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am encountering an error reading, no matching conversion for functional style cast from 'int' to 'TrashCan'.

here is the declaration in header:

```
class TrashCan
{
friend TrashCan operator +( TrashCan& left,
                          TrashCan& right);
public:
TrashCan();
int size=0;
int item=0;

void setSize(int);
void addItem();
```

here is my implementation:

```
TrashCan operator +(const TrashCan& left,
              const TrashCan& right) {
TrashCan t= TrashCan( left.size + right.size );
return( t );

}
```

here is the main with operator at bottom:

```
int main( ) {

cout << "Welcome to My TrashCan Program!" << endl;

TrashCan myCan;
TrashCan yourCan;

yourCan.setSize( 12 );
myCan.setSize( 12 );

yourCan.addItem( );
yourCan.addItem( );
myCan.addItem( );

myCan.printCan();
yourCan.printCan();

//TrashCan combined = yourCan + myCan;
```

Comment: You have `const` in your definition but not your declaration.

Comment: Can you please include the code where you try to operate on two `TrashCan` objects using `operator +`?  That could be the source of the error.  Also, if you could add what constructors the `TrashCan` class has, that will be a big help.  Or really, the entire declaration of `TrashCan`, if it's not too long.

Comment: @NicholasM I included more code in an edit as it is a pretty simple program.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

You declare your constructor like this: `TrashCan();`

But you call it like this: `TrashCan t= TrashCan( left.size + right.size );`.

You need to have a second constructor like `TrashCan(int nsize) : size(nsize) { }`.

godel9 already put the answer in the comments, but here's a working code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class TrashCan {
    // Your declaration did not match your definition
    // Need to put const here
    friend TrashCan operator +(const TrashCan& left,
                          const TrashCan& right);
    public:
        TrashCan(int nsize) : size(nsize) { }
        ~TrashCan() { }
        int size;                      
};

TrashCan operator +(const TrashCan& left,
              const TrashCan& right) 
{
    TrashCan t= TrashCan( left.size + right.size );
    return( t );
}

int main()
{
    TrashCan tc1(10);
    TrashCan tc2(20);

    std::cout << (tc1 + tc2).size;
    // outputs 30
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @aschepler Ah thanks for pointing that out. I didn't take a close look at OP's edit.